# Put own iPhone .app's on iPhone

Tags: iphone, signing, winscp

I made app1 and transfered it to my iPhone using WinSCP to ssh into my iPhone.
It shows up in my iPhone and runs.

Then I made app2 and transfered it to my iPhone.
Shows up and runs aswell..

My problem?
I only seem to be able to have 1 of them show at the same time.
I can either have app1 or app2, but not both at the same time.

I don't understand why

At first I thought maybe they're called the same thing or something..?
I changed the name.app to 1.app but it still showed up as Fake Code Sign(lol)
So I went to build settings -> bundle name and changed it to 1

I made sure the first one was called 1 and the second 2, but they still would not appear together...

So I thought, eh, maybe I should use a different code signing(only thing I could think of)
but it still doesn't work..

Anyone know what I have to do?

Comment: Try changing the bundle ID, not just the bundle's display name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the same bundle ID for both.  Check the `Info.plist` file for each application.

Comment: One question, though...
Shouldn't each project get its own default unique ID?
It said something like "OM.${PRODUCTNAME}"

Comment: Then it's using the product name in the bundle ID.  Check your build settings to see which product name you are using.